# keras LSTM model input and output dimensions mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, mismatch

```
model = Sequential()

    model.add(Embedding(630, 210))
    model.add(LSTM(1024, dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True))
    model.add(LSTM(1024, dropout = 0.2, return_sequences = True))
    model.add(Dense(210, activation = 'softmax'))

    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    filepath = 'ner_2-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.5f}.hdf5'
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor = 'loss', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True, mode = 'min')
    callback_list = [checkpoint]

    model.fit(X, y , epochs = 20, batch_size = 1024, callbacks = callback_list)
```

X: the input vector is of the shape (204564, 630, 1)

y: the target vector is of the shape (204564, 210, 1)

i.e. for every 630 inputs 210 outputs have to be predicted but the code throws the following error on compilation

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-05a6affb6217> in <module>()
     50 callback_list = [checkpoint]
     51 
---> 52 model.fit(X, y , epochs = 20, batch_size = 1024, callbacks = callback_list)
     53 print('successful')



ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected embedding_8_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (204564, 630, 1)
```

## Please someone explain why this error is occurring and how to solve this

Comment: you have a dimension too much, why is it (204564, 630, 1) and not just (204564, 630)?

Comment: Actually - it's not that for each of 630 sequence elements you have one of 210 predictions. You have 210 predictions for a whole sequence. Could you elaborate more on what your `y` represents?

Comment: It also seems that you wrongly defined the `Embedding` layer. What is your vocabulary size and the embedding dim you want to have?

Comment: @Marcin Mozejko                                                                                    May be you can give me some better ideas to tackle this problem:

Comment: i have to look at three word at a time and predict the next word(text generation problem) now each word has 3 tags so analyze 9 tags and predict 3 tags for the next subsequent word. There are 70 unique tags and one word can have at most 3 tags out of the 70. Any ideas?, I also need to improve the efficiency of the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says:

> Your first layer expects an input with 2 dimensions: (BatchSize, SomeOtherDimension). But your input has 3 dimensions (BatchSize=204564,SomeOtherDimension=630, 1).

Well... remove the 1 from your input, or reshape it inside the model:

**Solution 1 - Removing it from the input:**

```
X = X.reshape((204564,630))
```

**Solution 2 - Adding a reshape layer:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((630,),input_shape=(630,1)))
model.add(Embedding.....)
```